# How to draw this block diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I would like to draw this block diagram, but I'm having problems with all arrows and this last block in the first row. Can someone help me?

[image]

Here is what I have right now.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
 
% More defined colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns,fadings,matrix,arrows,calc,
    intersections,decorations.markings,
    positioning,external,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=6cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
}
 
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[input, name=input] {};
\node[sum, right=2cm of input, line width=0.25mm,] (sum) {};
 
\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    right=1.5cm of sum
]  (controller) {$A(s)$};

\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    right=1.5cm of controller
] (system1) {$B(s)$};


\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    right=1.5cm of system1
] (system) {$C(s)$};


\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm,
    right=1.5cm of system
] (system3) {$D(s)$};


\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    above = 1cm  of system1
]  (sensor) {$E(s)$};

\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    above = 1cm  of system
]  (sensor) {$F(s)$};

\node [draw,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    above = 1cm  of system3
]  (sensor3) {};

\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -- (system1.west) node[midway,above]{$x$};

\draw[-stealth] (system1.east) -- (system.west) node[midway,above]{$x$};

\draw[-stealth] (system1.east) -- (system.west) node[midway,above]{$x$};

\draw[-stealth] (system.east) -- (system3.west) node[midway,above]{$x$};

 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE community!

Sorry, but your sketch is not very clear, so I left out content of the far upper right node and just guess some connection between nodes.

[image]

At drawing above block diagram I use `chains` library for placing nodes in main branch of diagram and for some arrows use `ext.paths.ortho` library:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package,
                                    % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en
                positioning,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
    node distance = 8mm and 6mm,
      start chain = A going right,
       arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
     block/.style = {draw, thick, minimum height=11mm, minimum width=22mm},
       dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.2pt, node contents={}},
       sum/.style = {circle, draw, thick, inner sep=6pt, node contents={}}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes = {on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\coordinate (in);
\node[sum];                 % A-2
\node[block]    {$A(s)$};
\node[block]    {$B(s)$};
\node[block]    {$C(s)$};
\node[dot];
\node[block]    {$D(s)$};
\node[dot];                 % A-7
\coordinate (out);          
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw=none]   (A-8) to["$x$"] (out);
% top branch
\node [block, above=of A-4]  (sensor1) {$E(s)$};
\node [block, above=of A-5]  (sensor2) {$F(s)$};
\node [block, above=of A-7]  (sensor3) {};
% arrows not considered in the join macro
\draw[arr]  (sensor3) edge (sensor2)
            (sensor2) edge (sensor1);

\draw[arr]  ([xshift=-3mm] sensor1.south) |-| (A-3);
\draw[arr]  ([xshift=+3mm] sensor1.south) |-| ([xshift=-3mm] A-5.north);
\draw[arr]  ([xshift=+3mm] A-5.north) |-| (sensor3);

\draw[arr]  (A-6) |-      ([yshift=-6mm] sensor3.south) 
                                r-rl    ([yshift=-2mm] sensor3.east);
\draw[arr]  (A-8) |- ([yshift=2mm] sensor3.east);

\draw[->]   (A-8) r-du (A-2);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
One more guessing with a little bit improved code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package,
                                    % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en
                positioning,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
    node distance = 8mm and 6mm,
      start chain = A going right,
       arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
     block/.style = {draw, thick, minimum height=11mm, minimum width=22mm},
       dot/.style = {suspend join, 
                     circle, draw, fill, inner sep=1.2pt, node contents={}},         % changed
       sum/.style = {circle, draw, thick, inner sep=2pt, node contents={\huge +}}    % changed
        }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}   % new
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes = {on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\coordinate (in);
\node[sum];                             % A-2
\node[block]    {$A(s)$};
\node[block]    {$B(s)$};
\node[block]    {$C(s)$};
\node[dot, join=by -];    % changed
\node[block]    {$D(s)$};
\node[dot, join=by -];    % A-7,  changed
\coordinate (out);          
    \end{scope}
    \path[draw=none]   (A-8) to["$x$"] (out);
% top branch
\node [block, above=of A-4]  (sensor1) {$E(s)$};
\node [block, above=of A-5]  (sensor2) {$F(s)$};
\node [block, above=of A-7]  (sensor3) {};
% arrows not considered in the join macro
\draw[arr]  (sensor3) edge (sensor2)
            (sensor2) edge (sensor1);

\draw[arr]  ([xshift=-3mm] sensor1.south) |-| (A-3);
\draw[arr]  ([xshift=+3mm] sensor1.south) |-| ([xshift=-3mm] A-5.north);
\draw[arr]  (sensor3) |-| ([xshift=+3mm] A-5.north);    % changed

\draw[arr]  (A-6) |-      ([yshift=-6mm] sensor3.south) 
                                r-rl    ([yshift=-2mm] sensor3.east);
\draw[arr]  (A-8) |- ([yshift=2mm] sensor3.east);

\draw[->]   (A-8) r-du (A-2);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Zarko, thank you for your answer. It is event-triggering block that I am not sure how to draw :)

Comment: I can't compile this: ackage tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'ext.paths.ortho'. I looked for files named tikzlibraryext.paths.ortho.code.tex and pgflibraryext.paths.ortho.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees

Comment: @Andersa, if you check code carefully you should notice the comment where is given link to CTAN site, where you can find package `tikz-ext` which define among other libraries also  one used in my answer. If you not have instaled it, install it by utility of your LaTeX installation (in my case I use MiKTeX console).